# How do we capture the domain name from a url field in a formula

Tags: formula-field

I am trying to get the capture just the domain name from a website field in Account in a formula field.

For eg.

if website is  http://www.yahoo.com i need the formula field to display only yahoo. this should work if the website is put in as http://yahoo.com. Or if the url is https://na9.salesforce.com it should be salesforce

```
SUBSTITUTE(Website , LEFT(Website , FIND(".", Website )), NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of different cases that you need to work through. Here is the complete formula that worked for us:

```
SUBSTITUTE(
    IF(
        FIND(
            "/",
            IF(
                FIND("www.", Website) > 0,
                IF(
                    FIND("//", Website) > 0,
                    SUBSTITUTE(Website, LEFT(Website, FIND("//www.", Website) + 5), NULL),
                    Website
                ),
                IF(
                    FIND("//", Website) > 0,
                    SUBSTITUTE(Website, LEFT(Website, FIND("//", Website) + 1), NULL),
                    Website
                )
            )
        ) > 0, 
        LEFT(
            IF(
                FIND("www.", Website) > 0,
                IF(
                    FIND("//", Website) > 0,
                    SUBSTITUTE(Website, LEFT(Website, FIND("//www.",Website) + 5), NULL),
                    Website
                ),
                IF(
                    FIND("//", Website) > 0,
                    SUBSTITUTE(Website, LEFT(Website, FIND("//",Website) + 1), NULL),
                    Website
                )
            ),
            FIND(
                "/",
                IF(
                    FIND("www.", Website) > 0,
                    IF(
                        FIND("//", Website) > 0,
                        SUBSTITUTE(Website, LEFT(Website, FIND("//www.",Website) + 5), NULL),
                        Website
                    ),
                    IF(
                        FIND("//", Website) > 0,
                        SUBSTITUTE(Website, LEFT(Website, FIND("//", Website) + 1), NULL),
                        Website
                    )
                )
            ) - 1
        ),
        IF(
            FIND("www.", Website) > 0,
            IF(
                FIND("//", Website) > 0,
                SUBSTITUTE(Website, LEFT(Website, FIND("//www.", Website) + 5), NULL),
                Website
            ),
            IF(
                FIND("//", Website) > 0,
                SUBSTITUTE(Website, LEFT(Website, FIND("//", Website) + 1), NULL),
                Website
            )
        )
    ),
    'www.', 
    ''
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this is how I solved it.

If(BEGINS(Website, "www."), 
MID(Website, FIND('www.', Website, 1)+4, (LEN(Website) - FIND('www.', Website, 1)+4)),

If(BEGINS(Website, "http://"), 
MID(Website, FIND('http://', Website, 1)+7, (LEN(Website) - FIND('http://', Website, 1)+7)),

IF(BEGINS(Website, "https://"), 
MID(Website, FIND('https://', Website, 1)+8, (LEN(Website) - FIND('https://', Website, 1)+8)), 
Website 
)))

Answer (score 1):

I found there were additional variations in the URLs with some having www. and other without.  Same code structure, but additional searches to further capture the name:

If(BEGINS(Website, "www."), MID(Website, FIND('www.', Website, 1)+4, (LEN(Website) - FIND('www.', Website, 1)+4)),

If(BEGINS(Website, "http://www."), MID(Website, FIND('http://www.', Website, 1)+11, (LEN(Website) - FIND('http://www.', Website, 1)+11)),

If(BEGINS(Website, "https://www."), MID(Website, FIND('https://www.', Website, 1)+12, (LEN(Website) - FIND('https://www.', Website, 1)+12)),

If(BEGINS(Website, "http://"), MID(Website, FIND('http://', Website, 1)+7, (LEN(Website) - FIND('http://', Website, 1)+7)),

If(BEGINS(Website, "https://"), MID(Website, FIND('https://', Website, 1)+8, (LEN(Website) - FIND('https://', Website, 1)+8)), Website )))))

Answer (score 1):

This works for http://www.yahoo.com, http://yahoo.com,https://www.yahoo.com... and for http://www.yahoo.com/test1/test2 etc.

```
IF(FIND('/',SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Website, 'http://', NULL), 'https://', NULL), 'www.', NULL))>0,LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Website, 'http://', NULL), 'https://', NULL), 'www.', NULL),FIND('/',SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Website, 'http://', NULL), 'https://', NULL), 'www.', NULL))-1),SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Website, 'http://', NULL), 'https://', NULL), 'www.', NULL))
```

Comment: Works like a charm. you save my day thank you

Answer (score 0):

tried all the formulas provided as answers above. None of these seems to work. Found one in Salesforce help community which seems to work for me `see url below`. This was answered by Keiji Otsubo (Fukada Electric Co.,Ltd.)

pasting here for others:

```
left(
IF(OR(BEGINS(Website, "http://www"),BEGINS(Website, "https://www"), BEGINS(Website, "www.")),
    SUBSTITUTE(Website, LEFT(Website, FIND(".", Website)), NULL),
        IF(BEGINS(Website, "http://"),
            MID(Website, FIND('http://', Website, 1)+7, (LEN(Website) - FIND('http://', Website, 1)+7)),
                IF(BEGINS(Website, "https://"),
                    MID(Website, FIND('https://', Website, 1)+8, (LEN(Website) - FIND('https://', Website, 1)+8)),
                        Website
                )
        )
)
,FIND('.',
    IF(OR(BEGINS(Website, "http://www"),BEGINS(Website, "https://www"), BEGINS(Website, "www.")),
        SUBSTITUTE(Website, LEFT(Website, FIND(".", Website)), NULL),
            IF(BEGINS(Website, "http://"),
                MID(Website, FIND('http://', Website, 1)+7, (LEN(Website) - FIND('http://', Website, 1)+7)),
                    IF(BEGINS(Website, "https://"),
                        MID(Website, FIND('https://', Website, 1)+8, (LEN(Website) - FIND('https://', Website, 1)+8)),
                            Website
                    )
            )
    )
)-1)
```

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000DcN3eSAF