# finding domain name from website

Tags: formula, administration

I'm working on a formula field to capture the domain details from the website and I have created the below formula

```
If(NOT(ISBLANK(Website)),SUBSTITUTE(Website, LEFT(Website, FIND(".", Website)), NULL), Domain_from_lead__c )
```

It's working fine except for the below cases.

1. https://example.com
2. http://example.com
3. http://www.example.com/in/es

Could you please help me to handle these cases

Comment: A regex _may_ be necessary here, but I will say that a domain will never include a forward slash, so you can safely ignore forward slashes beyond `http(s)://` and any characters after that slash. Do you also need to account for subdomains? Like `maps.google.com` or `salesforce.stackexchange.com`?

Comment: [Check out the answer on this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63180/how-do-we-capture-the-domain-name-from-a-url-field-in-a-formula)